# About Data collection from PLC

Tags: android, plc

I don't have the plc connected to an opc server still I want real time data from the plc in any format. I want the timer's ACC data which I have to process on it further. How can I? please give steps of it cuz I'm new user of plc. I have micrologix 1400 plc from allen Bradley.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RSlinx to setup a "Topic" that allows Excel to to communicate with the PLC via DDE. Take a look at this example:
http://forums.mrplc.com/index.php?autocom=downloads&showfile=820

or Google: RSlinx DDE Excel, then you will find a lot of help.

Answer (score 0):

Allen Bradley makes a piece of hardware to communicate with a database.  Its really not easy to use.  I think this is one of the areas that Allen Bradley isn't good at.  Both Mitsubishi and Siemens have better products in this arena.

Here is a [link](http://www.sql4automation.com/en/features/functionality.php) to a company that focuses on collecting data off of Allen Bradley PLC's.  They sell hardware and software to write and read data to a SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to communicate the PLC with an Android device TCP seems to be the only solution and Modbus-TCP would be the most standard protocol,

I don't know if your PLC has Modbus-TCP connectivity or if some hardware should be added.

On Google Play store there are several Modbus_TCP client applications.

Answer (score 0):

AdvancedHMI will let you pull data into a .NET application with the included driver for the MicroLogix. The software is free to use.